# Java command only working in command line not in sh files

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, bash, java, path

I have recently attempted to install java on ubuntu server 12.04 LTS.

I wgetted the tar.gz file and extracted it to /opt/java and then added /opt/java/bin to the path variable. This all works correctly when typing "java" into the command line, however in scripts it acts as if the command does not exist. Thank you in advance for any answers :)

Comment: I think, you failed to make the script executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try putting the whole bin path into the sh file?

```
/path/to/my/bin blablablajavathigny
```

if it stil dont work, have you chmodded it?
like `chmod +x file.sh`

Comment: It is already 'chmod +x'ed. Also, is 'path/to/my/bin' supposed to mean '/opt/java/bin' (already done) or '/opt/java/bin/java'.

Comment: /opt/java7/bin/java is the correct one, good luck

Comment: @jhon01dav From the terminal, what is the output of `whereis java`?

Comment: "java: /usr/share/java /opt/java/bin/java"